# Use dictionary value to parse a string in python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to parse a string at a specified position which is pulled from a dictionary. I've only been working with python for a couple months and I can't figure out how to pull in the value correctly.

I've tried finding answers within posts about dictionaries, but I'm not seeing this specific question.

```
#pull in mods, excel file, and sheets needed

sourceIdDict={}

for x in range(10):
    source=str(insheet2.cell(x,0))
    numBgn=insheet2.cell(x,4)
    sourceIdDict[source]=numBgn

for count in range(500):
    crs=str(insheet1.cell(count,0))
    src=str(insheet1.cell(count,1))
    yrtr=str(insheet1.cell(count,2))
    tseg=str(insheet1.cell(count,3))
    uSeg=str(insheet1.cell(count,4))
    level=crs[sourceIdDict.get(src)]

#if condition met: write to output file

#close file
```

The last line seems to be the problem. I keep getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers.` I don't know why it isn't reading it as an integer, even when I use `crsBgn=int(insheet2.cell(x,4))`. source is the same info as src.

The other variables are string because they could have leading zeros, which I don't want dropped when it's written into excel.

Comment: Does type casting work? I.e. converting `sourceIdDict.get(src)` to `int(sourceIdDict.get(src))`?

Comment: You may be getting a non-integer from the dict or a None if the key isn't present, it depends on the input. I think you should replace the last line of first for by `sourceIdDict[source]=int(numBgn)`

Comment: You may get TypeErrors if numBgn can't be parsed, surround it by try/catch and handle it accordingly

Comment: @feliks No, then the error changes to TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: @geckos That gives TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Cell'

Comment: Thank you both. I managed to get a little further with this by printing everything. For some reason, my data was coming in differently from the 2 sheets and I needed to do some slicing to get it to match up correctly. I made a lot of changes trying to chase down exactly where everything goes wrong, so it's at least going wrong at the end now. Even though numBgn is now type int, it still won't slice at the value for source.

Comment: Glad you could gain more insight. We can't help you, because there is no way for us to reproduce your error. Try `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` just before the line that throws the error to manually examine your environment. You're on your own, good luck!